# What is the command to sign a message using a segwit private key using electrum 3?

Tags: electrum, segregated-witness, message-signing, message-verification

I want to sign and verify a message using a segwit private key that i generated with another application. How can I sign and verify a message using electrum 3 cli?

Answer (score 1):

Electrum provides `signmessage` and `verifymessage` commands that you can use to sign and verify messages.

For signing messages with a different private key, you will need to import it into the wallet.

Verifying a message does not require any additional work.

Answer (score 0):

First [convert and import the key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/70118/5273) then go to view menu > show addresses, switch to addressess tab, right click on the address and choose sign/verify.

However note that the format Electrum uses for signatures from bech32 address private keys may be different from what other apps/hardware wallets use so your generated signature may not verify in other wallets.