# Creating a new electrum 3 wallet file with an imported segwit private key

Tags: address, private-key, electrum, segregated-witness

I have a segwit private key that I generated from another app. How can I create a new electrum wallet file with just this private key in there?

I tried creating a new electrum 3 wallet with this command: **electrum create --segwit**

Then I tried to do an importpirvkey but it says that type of wallet doesnt support importing of addresses. How can I import my bc1 address into electrum as my only address?

Answer (score 4):

Use this python script:

```
from electrum import bitcoin

format,privkey,compressed=bitcoin.deserialize_privkey("<yourprivatekeyhere>")
print( bitcoin.serialize_privkey( privkey, compressed, "p2wpkh") )
```

Run the above in python 3 and then import the priv key it outputs into electrum as [per this guide](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/importing-your-private-keys-into-electrum/).

The reason you have to do this is because Electrum went its own way with the private key format. See the [release notes for 3.0](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/RELEASE-NOTES#L94).